# Running executable code within PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Please see the code that I have within the BODY of PHPMailer. System reports a Syntax error on the line $mail->Body .= ''. $row['updated_by'] . '';
I have read through documentation of PHPMailer but have not been able to find much about inserting PHP within the BODY part of the email.

$mail->Body    = <<

```
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered sortable">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Sales Agent</th>
                  <th>Company</th>
                  <th>Contact</th>
                  <th>Contact Medium</th>
                  <th>Contact Date</th>
                  <th>Result</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

              <?php 
                include 'database.php';
                $pdo = Database::connect();

                $yesterday =  date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',strtotime("-1 days"));
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer_history` WHERE `date_contacted` = '$yesterday'";
                $sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $sth->execute();

                foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) 

                {
                        $mail->Body .= '<tr>';
                        $mail->Body .= '<td>'. $row['updated_by'] . '</td>';
                        $mail->Body .= '<td>'. $row['company_name'] . '</td>';
                        $mail->Body .= '<td>'. $row['first_name'] . '</td>';
                        $mail->Body .= '<td>'. $row['contacted_by'] . '</td>';
                        $mail->Body .= '<td>'. $row['date_contacted'] . '</td>';
                        $mail->Body .= '<td>'. $row['last_result'] . '</td>';
                        $mail->Body .= '</td>';
                        $mail->Body .= '</tr>';
                }
               Database::disconnect();
              ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

END;

Comment: A dynamic HTML table doesn't sound like "runnable" code. Create your HTML table and use/paste that in your body, you should be fine. As for only showing the last result you should post the code you use to generate that table.

Comment: Show us your code otherwise all we can do is guess and can't really help you.

Comment: I am looking more for a guideline rather than correcting code. If you were to want to add an HTML table to the BODY of PHPMailer, what is the process.

Comment: You add an HTML table to the body as you would add anything to the body really: `$mail->Body = '<table><tr><td>table</td></tr></table>';` There's a [tutorial](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Tutorial) available you might want to read.

Comment: Perhaps I should change to say that, I want the results of an array to be presented within a table within the BODY of PHPMailer. Using something like, $input = $row["order_id"]; As soon as I add this code to the BODY, I cannot get it to work. It does allow me to however use a variable, but I need to return all of the results of a query in the table.

Comment: This is two separate things: create an HTML layout dynamically, then pass that to PHPMailer as your `Body`. PHPMailer has nothing to do with the creation of the `Body` element, it's up to you.

Comment: I have copied the working code (that works out of PHPMailer) into the BODY of PHPMailer. This line appears to have a syntax error. I have tried removing the echo                                        
 echo '<td>'. $row['updated_by'] . '</td>';

Comment: You're `echo`ing it - you don't want to do that as it just sends the output to the browser. Instead append each string to the `Body` element with `$mail->Body .= '<tr>';` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly execute db query and after that add result to the body.

```
<?php 

$history = '';

include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();

$yesterday =  date('Y-m-d 00:00:00',strtotime("-1 days"));
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `customer_history` WHERE `date_contacted` = '$yesterday'";
$sth = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute();

foreach ($sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row) 
{
    $history .= '<tr>';
    $history .= '<td>'. $row['updated_by'] . '</td>';
    $history .= '<td>'. $row['company_name'] . '</td>';
    $history .= '<td>'. $row['first_name'] . '</td>';
    $history .= '<td>'. $row['contacted_by'] . '</td>';
    $history .= '<td>'. $row['date_contacted'] . '</td>';
    $history .= '<td>'. $row['last_result'] . '</td>';
    $history .= '</td>';
    $history .= '</tr>';
}
Database::disconnect();

// Mail body
$mail->Body = <<<EOF
...
    <tbody>
        {$history}
    </tbody>
...
EOF;
```

Comment: Many thanks, problem solved. I had really been battling with this. Your explanation is great.